# Connection access database in java program

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am trying to connect my java program with a MS ACCESS database. I looked a lot on the internet, but I don't find my problem. I wrote the code:

```
private String dburl="jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb)};DBQ=Database1.mdb";
...
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
c=DriverManager.getConnection(dburl);
```

And I get the folowing error:

```
Errorjava.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name no t found and no default driver specified
```

I make a DNS from my database. And I tried a lot, but I keep having the error. I also try with the exact location where the database is, I tried to put the created DNS in the folder of my java program,...

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

If somehow possible, don't use a JdbcOdbc driver, but a pure JDBC-Driver for your database

OR

Try this:-

```
DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) 
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance());
c= DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,"","");
```

This will ensure that the "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver" class is loaded and connected to the DriverManager.

Comment: I get the same error with your code. How do I do to use a pure JDBC-driver ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message *"Data source name no t found and no default driver specified"* is all you need. It can't locate the database `Database1.mdb`. You might want to try specifying the absolute path to the driver.

Comment: I already tried with the absolute path, but it doesn't word neither. I wrote dburl="jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver(*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/Jurgen Decuyper/Documents/Database1.mdb";

Comment: Do you actually have the Access Driver installed?

Comment: You are not using a system DSN in your connection string.

Comment: And how do I use a system DSN in my connection string?

Comment: Use `jdbc:odbc:<name-of-your-dsn>`

Answer (score 0):

> How do I do to use a pure JDBC-driver ?

HXTT Access (a commercial pure Java type 4 driver) is at http://www.hxtt.com/access.html .